# Variable issue with jQuery Cycle Plugin

Tags: jquery, cycle

Can some one assist me on this?

**This is my JS**

```
 /* Soccer Call */   
      var hoverIn = function() {
          $('#soccer').cycle({
              fx: 'scrollLeft', 
              speed: 1000,
              timeout: 100 
           });
        },
          hoverOut = function() {
          $('#soccer').cycle({
               fx:'pause'
            });
          };

        $('#soccer').hover(hoverIn, hoverOut);
```

The error that i'm getting in my Console is

```
[cycle] unknown transition: pause ; slideshow terminating
```

[The jQuery Options are here](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution to my problem.

```
    var $ss = $('#soccer').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollLeft',
        timeout: 2000
    }).hover(

    function() {
        // on hover over, advance the slide
        $ss.cycle('next').cycle('resume');
    }, function() {
        // on hover out, pause
        $ss.cycle('pause');
    }).cycle('pause');
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like pause is not a supported value for fx.  Based on this, Im not totally sure but I believe you want:

```
 var hoverIn = function() {
   $('#soccer').cycle({
     fx : 'scrollLeft', 
     speed: 1000,
     timeout: 100 
   });
 }
 var hoverOut = function() {
   $('#soccer').cycle('pause');
 };

 $('#soccer').hover(hoverIn, hoverOut);
```